# Facebook tutorial add logout button but blank screen

Tags: ios, logout, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm very new to objective C. I followed the tutorial for integrating Facebook to iOS app and did nothing else. After I added the code for logout button stuff, I ran it and it gave me an error at line :
 `[self.viewController.view addSubview:logoutButton];` 
The error is "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b6c550".
I know this might be a stupid error but if anyone can point out where I'm wrong I would be very appreciated!

```
static NSString* kAppId = @"340105106048288";


// Method that gets called when the sign out button is clicked
- (void)logoutButtonClicked {
    [facebook logout];
}



- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
   (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

UIButton *logoutButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
logoutButton.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 200, 40);
[logoutButton setTitle:@"Log Out" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[logoutButton addTarget:self action:@selector(logoutButtonClicked)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.viewController.view addSubview:logoutButton];


facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:self];
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults
    objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
// This part, the authorize method will bring you to the authorization page
if (![facebook isSessionValid])
    [facebook authorize:nil];


    return YES;
}



// Pre iOS 4.2 support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

// For iOS 4.2+ support
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
        openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
     annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

// Save the user credential, specifically the access token and the expiration date to the user defaults
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
}


- (void) fbDidLogout {
// Remove saved authorization information if it exists
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]) {
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults removeObjectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using IB on your logoutButton, check if you have linked it to your object (xib) in the interface builder. Let me know if the error still occurs.

[EDIT]

```
 [self.viewController.view addSubview:logoutButton];
```

won't work. You're using storyboard, right? The initial values generated usually doesn't include "viewController" in the properties. You can only see the "window". There's no instance of the viewController which might have been the cause of the error.

Piece of advice, why don't you implement the whole thing in ViewController and use delegate only when it's necessary, instead.

And by the way, please show the link of that Facebook tutorial, so I can explain to you how it should be implemented.

Comment: I just created a new project using storyboard. I didn't change the code in viewcontroller.h and .m file. Do I need to do anything there? Or should I add something more to the appDelegate file? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Have you integrated the Facebook api in your new project? Run your project before and after you have included your Facebook API, and without the logout button. 

Unrecognized  selector is often caused by:
1. Wrong instance of an object (a controller for example)
2. Your method is not called. It may be that you're using IBAction and wasn't able to link it to your object. It could also be that you 're calling an undeclared method or an object.

Comment: I already included the api and everything works fine before the logout button step. I can see the authorization page too. I just followed the steps in the tutorial and create the project. Do I need to do anything else before the logout button step?

Comment: I just add all codes I added in the appDelegate file. I think it is dynamically created. I didn't add any button to the storyboard.

Comment: This is the tutorial. I moved all things to the controller file. The authorization part is alright. But the logout button still doesn't appear.

Comment: Try implementing the logout button to the RootViewController, then just call the methods via delegate.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now I met another problem. When I clicked the login button to Facebook in my app. It took me to a page that showed: An error occurred. Please try again later. And there is a Okey button on the top right. If I clicked that "Okey button" it took me to my Facebook Newsfeed page. Do you know why it keeps showing this error? Thanks!